# How can I add horizontal lines between my vertical lines in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, line

I have a dataframe **new** which looks like this:

```
> new
     group        date         relamount     average
1       1     2012-07-01       2.3498695     1.524178
2       1     2012-08-01       0.6984866     1.524178
3       2     2012-09-01       0.9079118     1.896867
4       2     2012-10-01       2.8858218     1.896867
5       3     2012-11-01       1.2406948     1.777372
6       3     2012-12-01       2.3140496     1.777372
7       4     2013-01-01       1.5904573     2.421820
8       4     2013-02-01       3.2531825     2.421820
9       5     2013-03-01       4.2962963     3.812503
10      5     2013-04-01       3.3287101     3.812503
11      6     2013-05-01       3.7698413     2.603770
12      6     2013-06-01       1.4376997     2.603770
13      7     2013-07-01       5.0687285     4.760392
14      7     2013-08-01       4.4520548     4.760392
15      8     2013-09-01       5.5063913     5.537038
16      8     2013-10-01       5.5676856     5.537038
17      9     2013-11-01       6.2686567     8.644863
18      9     2013-12-01      11.0210697     8.644863
```

I plot the data (`date` on x axis, `relamount` on y axis) and have `new$group` as **vertical lines**.

**What I want:**

**Horizontal lines** between the vertical lines based on `new$average`...so far tried to do it like this with `geom_segment`:
I know I have to have a specific start and end point for `geom_segment`, but maybe I can also do it like this? As expected it didn't work.

```
seq <- seq(2, nrow(df1), by=2)  # points for vertical lines
ggplot(new, aes(date, relamount)) +          # plot data 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = new$date[seq])     # create vertical lines
  geom_segment(data = new, aes(x = new$group,    # create horiz. lines 
                               y = new$average, 
                            xend = new$group +1, 
                            yend = new$average))
```

So I just want to have the red lines (`new$average`) between the vertical lines.

[image]

Comment: Where is `df1`? What packages are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry, df1 is my old dataframe to generate the new data frame...the only package I am using is ggplot().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)

new = read.table(text = "
group        date         relamount     average
1       1     2012-07-01       2.3498695     1.524178
2       1     2012-08-01       0.6984866     1.524178
3       2     2012-09-01       0.9079118     1.896867
4       2     2012-10-01       2.8858218     1.896867
5       3     2012-11-01       1.2406948     1.777372
6       3     2012-12-01       2.3140496     1.777372
7       4     2013-01-01       1.5904573     2.421820
8       4     2013-02-01       3.2531825     2.421820
9       5     2013-03-01       4.2962963     3.812503
10      5     2013-04-01       3.3287101     3.812503
11      6     2013-05-01       3.7698413     2.603770
12      6     2013-06-01       1.4376997     2.603770
13      7     2013-07-01       5.0687285     4.760392
14      7     2013-08-01       4.4520548     4.760392
15      8     2013-09-01       5.5063913     5.537038
16      8     2013-10-01       5.5676856     5.537038
17      9     2013-11-01       6.2686567     8.644863
18      9     2013-12-01      11.0210697     8.644863
", header=T)

# get points for vertical lines
seq <- seq(2, nrow(new), by=2) 

ggplot() +    
  geom_line(data=new, aes(date, relamount, group=1)) +             # plot line of data points
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(new$date[seq])) +             # plot vertical lines
  geom_segment(data=new[seq,], aes(x=as.numeric(date)-2,           # plot horizontal lines (segments)
                                   xend=as.numeric(date), 
                                   y=average, 
                                   yend=average), col="red") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = new$date[seq], labels = new$date[seq]) # adjust x axis labels
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just one thing: do I need the tidyverse package? I can't load it properly, it gives an error saying "package readxl has no namespace" and when trying to load readxl, it also doesn't work.

Comment: If I execute the code without loading tidyverse, I just get the ending point of the red lines in the plot

Comment: It should work OK with just the `ggplot2` package only.

Comment: Okay, works now, I just had to change the date to a factor...Thanks!